# Installed applications missing in Apps menu

Tags: appmenu

I am running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 (previously 16.04) and it happens that some installed software (like [Anydesk](https://anydesk.com/en/)) despite being correctly installed and run from command, does not appear in the application menu.

Does anyone knows how to make the menu application to show this installed software?

Comment: You can try to run Main Menu editor with `mozo` command and check them here.